# How to reset SQLite value after 24 hours?

Tags: android, sqlite

I've look around a lot and can't find a relatable answer. I'm pretty sure it's trival but I would be really greatful if anyone could help.

I have an android app that uses a mysql databse and an sqllite one to store logged user info. I have a "walks" field where user puts how many walks a day his dog goes for. This data is send to mysql during registration and after user logges in data is retrived from mysql and stored in sqlite. User can then log walks into the app so the counter goes from, for example, "3" to "0" after those three walks a day. How can I reset the walks value in sqlite database after 24 hours in the simplest way possible?

Comment: Maybe when somone entry the app get system time and when he enters again get time another and check if there is 24h difference between this times. If it's > 24h clear your database, if not do nothing.

Comment: thanks, but if I do that, that means I have to fetch all the data from mysql every 24h right?

Comment: I dont quite understand what do you want exactly to do but maybe clear just this walks value every 24 hour.

Comment: I want the "walks" value restored to the one fetched from mysql every 24 hours since people typically go for walks with dogs everyday :P

Comment: According to your question--"How can I reset the walks value in sqlite database after 24 hours in the simplest way possible?"  Quite simple: Add the system time to a `SharedPreference` at the time you wish to begin the 24hr period. Then when you open the app check the time difference to time saved in the `SharedPreference`. if the time is greater than the 24hrs then take whatever action you need to perform otherwise do whatever else you think needs to be done--whatever that is!

Answer (score 0):

I think [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms) is one of the good approach to this question. the easiest way to handle this is to check the database when the app/activity is started, and if the last access is from a date older than today, delete everything.
I hope this might be helpful.

Comment: I think I can use the AlarmManager. If I put the value fetched from mysql in sqlite and also in a constant than at midnight I can replace the value in sqlite with the constant value. Thanks! I will try it!

Comment: Shooting at a fly with a canon! One `SharedPreference` and five lines of code is all you need.